# Connectivity and product

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces. Is there any relation between
Connectivity of $X\times Y$ and connectivity of $X$ and $Y$?

I think by Kunneth formula, it must be $Conn(X\times Y)\leq\min\{Conn(X), Conn(Y)$}$ and I am wondering, How can be far from each others?

Answer (score 5):

You have $\pi_n(X\times Y, (x_0, y_0)) \cong \pi_n(X, x_0) \times \pi_n(Y, y_0)$, so $\pi_n(X\times Y, (x_0, y_0))$ is trivial if and only if both $\pi_n(X, x_0)$ and $\pi_n(Y, y_0)$ are trivial. So indeed the connectivity of the product is always the minimum of the connectivities of the factors.

---

Since some people seem to not agree that this is enough to show the desired equality, let me elaborate.

For a pointed topological space $(X,x_0)$ we say $X$ is $n$-connected when $\pi_k(X,x_0)=0$ for all $k\le n$. We define the connectivity of $X$ as the largest $n$ such that $X$ is $n$-connected.

Now the connectivity of $X\times Y$ is the largest $n$ such that $\pi_k(X\times Y, (x_0,y_0))=0$ for all $k\le n$. Now, as pointed out above, homotopy groups behave well under products, *i.e.* $\pi_n(X\times Y, (x_0, y_0)) \cong \pi_n(X, x_0) \times \pi_n(Y, y_0)$, so the connectivity of $X\times Y$ is the largest $n$ such that *both* $X$ and $Y$ are $n$-connectecd, which is in fact the minimum of the connectivities.

Comment: @DanielValenzuela Why? I added some elaboration.

Comment: I thought the question was about being connected (not n-connected).